# What role does the const keyword play when declaring a pointers like "int * a,const * c;"

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

```
int n = 1;
int * a,const * c= &n;
```

what I want to know is the role of const that is behind '* c'.
I debugged with visual studio, but cant find the that const keyword's role.
I expected c would be const int * type. but it was just int* type.

I already checked it that c is not int const * type. (with visual studio)

```
    int n = 1;

    int * a,const * c = &n;

    a = c = &n;
    *c = 234;

    printf("%d", *c);
```

If c is const int* type, this code would not work. but it works.

And also I already know the differences between const int*, int const*, int * const. Don't tell like I don't know about those things.

Of course, i know this coding style is bad. but I just want to know if the const keyword is simply disappearing and not performing any role, or if it is performing a role that I have not yet discovered.

I already read this page https://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#whitespace
but that doesnt resolve my question.

Comment: Doesn't compile with **clang++**.

Comment: MSVC also gives a warning for me: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4228?view=msvc-170

Comment: Which language are you asking about? You tagged two different languages. Don't do that. Since you linked to a C++ FAQ, I'm assuming you're asking about C++ and adjusted the tags accordingly. If you meant to ask about C, swap the tags.

Comment: sry i thought my question could adjust C and C++ so i tagged both. i won't do that again